# Firebase - update doc with where condition

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to update a Firebase document only when it meets a where condition?

Something like

```js
firebase.firestore()
        .collection('friends')
        .where('name', '==', 'Steven')
        .update({
          name: "Steve"
        })
```

or do I have to make a query, save all doc id's and update them after I collected the ids?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firestore (like most NoSQL databases) doesn't support update queries. You'll need to: 1. run the query, 2. loop over the results, 3. update each of them.

Comment: Thank you Frank :)